# Trimming NAs based on column subset - a more elegant solution?

Tags: r

A New Year's quandary for the stackoverflow community which has been quite the help by reading posts and answers in the past (this is my first question). I've found a work around, but I'm wondering if other approaches/solutions might be suggested.

I am attempting to remove trailing NA's from a large `data.frame`, but those NA's are only found in a few of the columns of the `data.frame` and I would like to retain all columns in the output. Here is a representative data subset.

```
df=data.frame(var1=rep("A", 8), var2=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"), var3=c(0,1,NA,2,3,NA,NA,NA), var4=c(0,0,NA,4,5,NA,NA,NA), var5=c(0,0,NA,0,2,4,NA,NA))
```

#### Goals of the process:

1. Trim trailing NAs based on NA presence in var3,var4 and var5
2. Retain all columns in final output
3. Only remove trailing NAs (i.e. row 3 remains in record as a placeholder)
4. Only trim if all columns have an NA (i.e. row 7 and 8, but not row 6)

Based on these goals, the solution should remove the last two rows of df:

```
df.output = df[-c(7,8),]
```

The behaviour of na.trim (in the zoo package) is ideal (as it limits removal to those NA's at the end of the data.frame, with sides="right"), and my work-around involved altering the na.trim.default function to include a subset term.

Any suggestions? Many thanks for any help.

EDIT: Just to complete this question, below is the function I created from the na.trim.default code which also works, but as noted, does require loading the zoo package.

```
na.trim.multiplecols <-  function (object, colrange, sides = c("both", "left", "right"),     is.na = c("any","all"),...) 
{
is.na <- match.arg(is.na)
nisna <- if (is.na == "any" || length(dim(object[,colrange])) < 1) {
complete.cases(object[,colrange])
}
else rowSums(!is.na(object[,colrange])) > 0
idx <- switch(match.arg(sides), left = cumsum(nisna) > 0, 
            right = rev(cumsum(rev(nisna) > 0) > 0), both = (cumsum(nisna) > 
                                                               0) &       rev(cumsum(rev(nisna)) > 0))
if (length(dim(object)) < 2) 
object[idx]
else object[idx, , drop = FALSE]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Edit:` First solution using base `rle` and `apply`

```
t <- rle(apply(as.matrix(df[,3:5]), 1, function(x) all(is.na(x))))
r <- ifelse(t$values[length(t$values)] == TRUE, t$lengths[length(t$lengths)], 0)
head(df, -r)
```

Second solution using `Rle` from package `IRanges`:

```
require(IRanges)
t <- min(sapply(df[,3:5], function(x) {
    o <- Rle(x)
    val <- runValue(o)
    if (is.na(val[length(val)])) {
        len <- runLength(o)
        out <- len[length(len)]
    } else {
        out <- 0
    }
}))
head(df, -t)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I've heard of rle before but never implemented it, I can how useful it might be moving forward. A small point is that because my data.frame includes many instances that had no NAs at the end, the head(df, -r) call doesn't work when r returns 0. I just wrote some different code to use r to count back from the length of df and drop off those rows.

Answer (score 1):

Something based on `max(which(!is.na()))` will work.  We use this to find the largest index of non-missing data from the columns of interest.

Using your df

```
ind <-  max(max(which(!is.na(df$var3))),
        max(which(!is.na(df$var4))),        
        max(which(!is.na(df$var5)))) 

df[1:ind, ]

   var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
 1    A    a    0    0    0
 2    A    b    1    0    0
 3    A    c   NA   NA   NA
 4    A    d    2    4    0
 5    A    e    3    5    2
 6    A    f   NA   NA    4
```