# Removing specific NAs from the vector without using loop

Tags: r, while-loop, na

I am looking for the fastest way to remove NAs ONLY from the end of a vector:

`vec <- c(1:5, NA, 6:10, NA, NA, NA)`

so the result is:

```
> vec
[1]  1  2  3  4  5 NA  6  7  8  9 10
```

The only solution I have found so far is 'while' looped from the last element of  the vector, e.g.:

```
i = length(vec)
while(is.na(vec[i]==TRUE)){
vec <- vec[1:i-1]
i = i-1
}
```

Is there any better solution (excluding loops)?

Comment: Using `zoo` package you can do `na.trim(vec, sides = "right")`

Comment: @Ben Thank you! Any ideas using base?

Comment: In base R: `vec[1:max(which(!is.na(vec)))]`?

Comment: Yes :) I have just noticed it in the other post. Thank you anyway Ben!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found a solution in Tony Ladson's answer to:
[Trimming NAs based on column subset - a more elegant solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143650/trimming-nas-based-on-column-subset-a-more-elegant-solution)

```
vec[1:max(which(!is.na(vec)))]
```

does the job.